# Struggling to come up with SQLAlchemy model relation

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

SQL newbie here, bear with me.

I am trying to store data with headlines from different news sites. Trying to figure out proper DB structure and SQLAlchemy models, but for now it seems like I have trouble grasping how to create proper relationship.

For now I've ended up with following `models.py` file:

```
class Headline(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'headlines'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    headline = Column(DateTime)
    time_stamp = Column(String)


class NewYorkTimes(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'newyorktimes'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    headline_id = Column(ForeignKey(Headline.id))

    headlines = relationship(
        'Headline',
        primaryjoin="and_(NewYorkTimes.headline_id==Headline.id)"
    )


class Times(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'times'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    headline_id = Column(ForeignKey(Headline.id))

    headlines = relationship(
        'Headline',
        primaryjoin="and_(Times.headline_id==Headline.id)"
    )
```

I am really not sure whether this kind of relationship is even correct... I'd wish to store all the headlines in `headlines` table, with timestamp and text content and while appending this table with new headline, I'd like to specify what site it was gathered from, so THIS headline id is added to site-specific table.

I used to store data in site-specific tables, but I believe this is just plain wrong solution - there was for example table `Times` with columns `id`, `headline`, `time_stamp` and tables for other sites had exactly same structure, but creating SQLAlchemy models for this denies probably everything what DRY is about.

Comment: Why not include a "publication" column in your headlines table to differentiate where the headline came from?

Comment: Haha! Oh snap, you are right, that's just an example of me tunneling to think in the way my previous solution was designed. You are 100% right, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try a different approach, where you have one table (`Publications`, say) for all of your news sources, rather than a separate table for each source. In this approach, `Times`, `NewYorkTimes` and whatever else you have will all be entries in the `Publications` table.

Also, you seem to have mixed up the column type for your headline and time_stamp columns above.

```
 class Headline(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'headlines'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    headline = Column(String)
    time_stamp = Column(Datetime)
    publication_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('publications.id'))

class Publication(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'publications'
    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    headlines = relationship('Headline', backref="publication")
```

Using `backref` on the `headlines` relationship will automatically put a relationship on the `Headline` table called `publication`. See sqlalchemy docs on [one to many relationships](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many) and [backref](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/backref.html#relationships-backref).

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the approach I was aiming at. (And obviously I've made mistake rewriting code, eh!)
I think for now I will opt with @Blue Star solution, since it's probably most simple and adequate solution for this case. Thank you for your input! Greatly appreciated!